# Stop request of anchor tag on click using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, anchor, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have an anchor tag with `href="http://www.abc.com/page/1"` attribute.It is an anchor link of a pagination feature.

When I click on this anchor, by default 'www.abc.com/page/1' gets loaded.

Now I want to disable this request using javascript/jquery.means page should not load. I have to use this whole link `'http://www.abc.com/page/1'` in an ajax call when some one clicks one the anchor link. I can't make a new attribute to this link either programatically or jquerying.

Reason(programtically): this is already working pagination feature and moving this link to other/new attribute will AFFECT whole application.

Reason(jquery): these links get loaded ajaxily, so I can't modify them on page load or on ajax success as it will also AFFECT whole app.

So on click event of this link I used `return false;` inside live function. But request is going.

I had gone through many question on stackoverflow and there answers: `'e.preventDefault', 'e.stopPropogation'` are also not working.

How can it be achived using jquery as I have to pass this link in an ajax call?Do I need anything extra to make e.preventDefault, e.stopPropogation to work.

Comment: Do you mean `stopImmediatePropagation`?

Comment: I there any function stopImmediatePropogation()? I don't know and even I didn't found any while exploring :(

Comment: I used it as per your comment, its also not working :(

Comment: Can you post relevant portion of your code? Theoretically, `preventDefault` _should_ work.

Comment: $('.Paginator').die('click').live('click', function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); OR
        var clickedUrl = $(this).attr('href');         // will be used for ajax call
        alert(clickedUrl);
    });

Comment: OR was posted by mistake.Assume its not there ;)

Comment: I tried `preventDefault` in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wxY3/2/) and it's working here. Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I m looking for same, but its not working in my application... :(

Comment: `die` and `live` are no longer recommended according to jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/die/). Have you tried using `on` and `off` instead?

Comment: ya.. I have heard and used on/off one,two time. But in my app, DOM loaded anchor is also redirected. e.preventdefault is not working. Is it possible because of twitter bootstrap library files.I am using it.